# Backend CMS to upload small documents on a webpage

Tags: php, html, wordpress, web

I have a website I'm working on for a friend where he wants to update it periodically, by adding text to a website. Is there some sort of CMS that could help him do this, without him having to edit the html by hand? I've already written the html, so I don't think something like wordpress would help. But I really have no clue, I'm brand new to web dev.

Comment: A CMS would be very helpful for your friend. You should be able to search for all the info you need. I would recommend you trying a modern CMS, not wordpress. btw this question is not fit, it is too broad. You should delete it before it is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've already written the html, so I don't think something like wordpress would help.

You can easily transform your static HTML layout and pages into a WordPress theme. But there are many other CMSs out there (small ones if you only need some basic features).

For this project I would go with WordPress, it's well-documented, easy-to-use and the community is great.

Comment: With any project I would avoid Wordpress unless there is a very specific reason.

Comment: Okay, it's up to you, but let's recommend something else. I think for a beginner it could be good choice (not for learning from the source code, of course, but the templating works and the 'loop' is easy to understand).

Comment: That is fair, we all have our preferences. I think for a beginner (especially a aspiring webdeveloper) it would be a horrible choice, being stuck in past era of php.